# Topology of two letters

Tags: general-topology

In the book of Buskes and van Rooij on *Topological Spaces*, there is an interesting introductory example on how the notion of topology arose from the distinction between several geometrical forms. Rigorously speaking, two forms are topologically distinguishable if they are not homeomorphic.

Consider the topology of the two letters: $T$ and $C$, on the plane. They are not diffeomorphic (at the intersection point of the letter $T$). The above textbook seems to imply that they are not homeomorphic.

The two curves are compact, simply connected. I tried to construct an explicit homeomorphism, but no advance for now.

My question is, are these two curves homeomorphic? If yes, what might be a homeomorphism? If no, why?

Comment: As you say, $T$ and $C$ are not homeomorphic, so any attempt to construct a homeomorphism between them will be in vain.

Comment: Not-entirely-irrelevant nitpickery: the T and C that appear in your answer _are_ homeomorphic; both of them are homeomorphic to a closed disc. That is to say, there is thickness to the strokes of these letters as they're written, and that thickness changes the answer...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I cannot oppose to that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not homeomorphic. You can remove a point from $T$ that cuts it into three connected parts. You can't with $C$. That prevents a homeomorphism.

The $T$ isn't a "curve" - you can't parameterize it with a line segment.

Answer (score 2):

They are not homeomorphic because every point of C cuts C into
exactly two parts but not every point cuts T into exactly two
parts.

Comment: All points of $C$ except $2$, of course. $T$ has $3$ such exception points.

Comment: Four exceptions, actually: three end points (which don't really split it) and the intersection point (which splits it into three)

Comment: And of course those exceptions only exist if we consider the intervals of these letters to be closed, rather than open; there's no clear indication one way or the other.